# Vue.js form page loses its data when coming back from a new page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a Vue.js page that is basically one big textarea.  If the user taps "Settings" on that page and opens the Settings page, then goes back to the original page, the textarea data is all gone.  Surely there must be an easy way of not losing everything without saving it to a database or something, right?

I'm using Vue Router.

Does Vue Router have something like a modal window (but for use in a smart phone app) that can be dismissed so everything underneath is saved?

Answer (score 1):

I would encode the form ID in the route path, and set [`props=true`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components) so that the ID is passed to the component's prop:

```js
// router.js
export default new VueRouter(
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/form/:id",
      name: "form",
      component: () => import("@/components/MyForm.vue"),
      props: true
    }
  ]
)

// MyForm.vue
export default {
  props: {
    id: {
      type: [Number, String],
      default: 0,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      text: "The text " + this.id,
    };
  },
}
```

Then use [`<keep-alive>`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/built-in-components.html#keep-alive) to reuse [cached views](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view), and use the route's full path as the `key` for `router-view`:

```html
<keep-alive>
  <router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
</keep-alive>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reuse-cached-components-in-vue-router-forked-2u9u9?file=/src/App.vue:369-444)

Comment: Thanks Tony.  I looked through your demo, and it works.  However, when I pass in arguments into the component, like this: <router-link :to="{ name: 'myform', params: { userId: 123 }}">My Form</router-link> I can only do it once, the first time. After that, the component always receives the params of the first call.  My form page doubles as a view page, where the textarea is read-only until made editable.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reuse-cached-components-in-vue-router-forked-vy3nl  I would like the textarea to show the ID for each link, but it only shows on the first link.